# How do I run MikTeX update wizard on Windows 8?

Tags: miktex, updating

I have MikTex 2.9. When I run MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\mpm_mfc.exe and click Task->Update Wizard it says "The update wizard could not be found."

How do I update packages?

**Edit:**

The update wizard is

'MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-update.exe'

or

'MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-update_admin.exe'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update wizard is

'MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-update.exe'

or

'MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-update_admin.exe'

Answer (score 0):

To update miktex you don't need to run the exe file. Press the windows button on your keyboard and start typing "update" (without the quotes). Windows will offer you some options, two of which will read "update" or "update (admin)" with miktex symbol on it. Click the one you like. I hope you know the rest.

Comment: It looks like when you install TexWorks it automatically installs portable version of MikTeX which doesn't show up in Windows search.
Anyway, I already added the answer.